# mysql query takes 13min to run

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables, and i am joining them using the code below

- `orders` has 30k rows
- `orders_details` has over 100k rows
- `services` has 4 rows

when I execute the script below in `Fish Database.net`, it takes over 13mins to run before displaying the result!!!

```
select 
  `o`.`created` AS `created`,
  sum(`o`.`total`) AS `total`,
  sum(`o`.`paid`) AS `paid`,
  `od`.`service_id` AS `service_id`,
  `s`.`name` AS `grp` 
from ((`orders` `o` 
  left join `orders_details` `od` on
    (
      (`od`.`order_id` = `o`.`id`)
    )) 
  left join `services` `s` on
    (
      (`s`.`id` = `od`.`service_id`)
    )) 
group by 
  `od`.`service_id`,
  `o`.`created`,
  `s`.`name` 
order by 
  `o`.`created`
```

- all column names with `id` are integer primary key columns
- created is a datetime column
- total, paid are decimal(10,2) columns
- name is a varchar (60) columns

Here is the explain result

**EDITS**

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra

1   SIMPLE  o   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    23558   Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  od  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    40304   
1   SIMPLE  s   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   mydb.od.service_id  1
```

I can i improve/find the bottleneck ??

Comment: try add indexes to foreign keys

Comment: show us the EXPLAIN of your query to see which index was used

Comment: possible indices needed `order_id`, `service_id`,`created` and `name` if not already done. However `explain` of the above query will help to analyze more so please post the result of explain into the question.

Comment: @BerndBuffen pls check the edits

Comment: From the explain its pretty clear its using filesort and since you are not using any limit the order by clause will lag things. Add index on `created` and in addition the joining columns also needs indexing `order_id`, `service_id`. Finally try liming the records while selecting, its not a wise idea to select all the records from such a big table even with proper indexing since the network lag could cause a big delay.

Comment: you can see thats no index was used. so create index ids on each table and one on the fields   `od`.`service_id`,
  `o`.`created`,
  `s`.`name`  and test it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of (unuseful) nested  () can degrading performance then 
try remove unseful ()
Be sure you have correct index on od.order_id, o.id , s.id , od.service_id

```
  select 
    o.created AS created,
    sum(o.total) AS total,
    sum(o.paid) AS paid,
    od.service_id AS service_id,
    s.name AS grp 
  from orders o 
    left join orders_details od on  od.order_id = o.id 
    left join services s on s.id = od.service_id 
  group by 
    od.service_id,
    o.created,
    s.name 
  order by 
    o.created
```

for a better reading   i have removed also backtics .. you don't have resersved  words  od multi words column name  so should not be needed)

Answer (score 0):

There are steps to find bottlenecks in sql script.

1. First of all,examine the execution plans and query statistics.
2. Execution plan will tell you where is the bottleneck.
3. Depending on the problem, create indexes and then again examine execution plan.
4. Apply pagination when needed. Sending data in batches also can make difference.